# R .libPaths() different in RStudio and in terminal - how to update on terminal

Tags: r, terminal

I'm not sure if this question has been asked before, but I didn't see anything come up at first glance. I am struggling with R library paths when trying to run an R script from the console using:

```
Rscript myfile.R
```

The libraries loaded in myfile.R are not loading up correctly. In RStudio, my library path is:

```
# run from console in RStudio
> .libPaths()
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library"

> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin15.6.0                
system         x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          4.1                         
year           2017                        
month          06                          
day            30                          
svn rev        72865                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
nickname       Single Candle
```

However, when I check the library path of R from the command line like so, I receive the following wrong path:

```
Rscript -e 'print(.libPaths())'
[1] "/Users/Home/anaconda2/lib/R/library"

Rscript -e 'print(version)'
               _                           
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin11.4.2                
system         x86_64, darwin11.4.2        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          2.2                         
year           2015                        
month          08                          
day            14                          
svn rev        69053                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
nickname       Fire Safety
```

The RStudio path returned is actually not showing the prefix, which is actually:

```
/Users/Home/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library
```

So my question is, how do I change the wrong path (run in terminal) to the right path (run in RStudio) for my R libraries with .libPaths() ?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you check the result of  `R.version` in both?

Comment: I edited the post with this info - different versions of R